# An Equivalence condition for $u,v$- node cut (or $u,v$-separator)

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

How can prove the only if part of the following property. It seems easy, but I can not find a proof.

Given $U\subseteq V$ and a nonadjacent pair of nodes $u, v\in U$, there exists a path in $G(U)$ between u and v if and only if all uv-node cuts S are such that $S \cap U \neq \emptyset$.